# How to make buttons in Java JFrame appear under each other?

Tags: java, button

As of now, in `Java` I have only been using `FlowLayout();` to make buttons, and textfields, to appear side by side each other.

I am trying to make a calculator and I am wondering how I could make the buttons appear under each other? For example if I could make `FlowLayout();` to go to the next line, kind of like `System.out.println();`

Any video, or code (with explanation would have been very helpful).

I have only made two very simple programs (one where you press a button that is red, and it turns blue), and the other where you write in some numbers and it converts to another currency.

I am a beginner at using `Jframe`(and `Java` in general), so I need my stuff in baby steps.

Comment: You might try a grid layout. Try here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Comment: On top of Jack's suggestion, you should check out BoxLayout also

Comment: BoxLayout is what you want

Comment: I am not sure which one to pick yet, because I haven't completely understood any of them. Do I need to combine them with JPanel..? which I haven't used yet either.

Comment: [Basic Calculator using Java Swing](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56718/basic-calculator-using-java-swing-and-awt)